# Get rows with upline value

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

Having the following data in `Users` table,

```
Id    Upline   Role    Username
----------------------------------
1      NULL      1       Admin
2      Admin     2       A10
3      A10       3       A1010
4      A1010     4       A101010
5      Admin     2        B2
6      B2        3        B3
7      B3        4        B4
```

To select the A line users, the result will have:

```
Id    Upline   Role    Username
----------------------------------
2      Admin     2       A10
3      A10       3       A1010
4      A1010     4       A101010
```

To select the B line users, the result will have:

```
Id    Upline   Role    Username
----------------------------------
5      Admin     2        B2
6      B2        3        B3
7      B3        4        B4
```

Given that now I have a user with random role, say
A101010, can a linq query that A101010 upline users?

```
Repository.Where(x=>x.Username==Upline && x.Role =Role+1);
//too bad this can only use to select exactly one upline right above the user.
```

However in sql this is achievable with :

```
WITH UserList  AS (
SELECT Username, Role, Upline from Users where Username = 'A101010'
UNION ALL
Select A.Username, Role, A.Upline
 FROM Users A
 INNER JOIN UserList X ON A.Username = X.Upline
) select * from UserList
```

Desired Results:

```
Id    Upline   Role    Username
----------------------------------
2      Admin     2       A10
3      A10       3       A1010
```

Example 2
Given that now I have a user B3, 
Desired Results:

```
Id    Upline   Role    Username
----------------------------------
5      Admin     2        B2
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want to select users that have the same Upline and Role as the parameter you are passing? Or do you want to query for all users whose name starts without the Dame letter as the Upline param (in your example, It would bem 'A', as the passes Upline is 'A1010')?

Comment: yes, it should return the A line users only. I just edited the question.

Comment: This is a hierarchy, users and who they report to right? In that case no Linq and EF doesn't do hierarchical queries on relational data to arbitrary levels. You need to either use raw SQL or make it a function an map that to a .net function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        class Userlist
        {
            public string Upline { get; set; }
            public int Role { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }

            public Userlist(string upline, int role, string userName)
            {
                Upline = upline;
                Role = role;
                Username = userName;
            }
         }


        List<Userlist> users = new List<Userlist>()
        {
            new Userlist("Admin", 2, "a10"),
            new Userlist("a10", 3, "a1010"),
            new Userlist("Admin", 2, "B2"),
            new Userlist("b2", 3, "b3"),

        };

        var userList = users.Where(user => user.Username == "a1010");

        var q = (from u in users
                 join x in userList
            on u.Username equals x.Upline
            select u).Concat(userList).ToList();
```